# Configuring Jenkins + git plugin on a mac is causing git clone to hang

Tags: macos, git, jenkins

I'm currently setting up Jenkins on a mac mini server running Lion (10.7.4) and I'm experiencing some issues with git/github integration.

To troubleshoot the issues I'm having, I've setup a test job with only the very basics, in this case, just the git repository. The job should simply clone the remote repo.
This is what's currently happening:

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/fr-develop-latest
Checkout:fr-develop-latest / /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/fr-develop-latest - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@1eaaf438
Using strategy: Default
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository origin
```

... and it simply hangs there for a long time (eventually it times out).

I obviously searched for this around for this and found a couple of people with the same issue, but no solution.

To further troubleshoot the problem I tried a few things:

. I've added an "Execute Shell" build step running only a simple `export` command. Here's the output of that:

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/test
[test] $ /bin/sh -xe /var/folders/05/tx3h6q9d0fd357pwxqswnqb400007v/T/hudson3541244199270773922.sh
+ export
export BUILD_ID="2012-10-10_14-13-21"
export BUILD_NUMBER="16"
export BUILD_TAG="jenkins-test-16"
export BUILD_URL="http://ctx.local:8080/job/test/16/"
export EXECUTOR_NUMBER="0"
export HOME="/Users/Shared/Jenkins"
export HUDSON_COOKIE="19f08f0b-059d-40b9-9672-ead63c741910"
export HUDSON_HOME="/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home"
export HUDSON_SERVER_COOKIE="82054d3c12fc596dd66eabce21a6bf3e"
export HUDSON_URL="http://ctx.local:8080/"
export JAVA_ARCH="x86_64"
export JAVA_MAIN_CLASS_63290="Main"
export JENKINS_HOME="/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home"
export JENKINS_SERVER_COOKIE="82054d3c12fc596dd66eabce21a6bf3e"
export JENKINS_URL="http://ctx.local:8080/"
export JOB_NAME="test"
export JOB_URL="http://ctx.local:8080/job/test/"
export LOGNAME="jenkins"
export NODE_LABELS="master"
export NODE_NAME="master"
export OLDPWD
export PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
export PWD="/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/test"
export SECURITYSESSIONID="186ae"
export SHELL="/bin/bash"
export SHLVL="1"
export TMPDIR="/var/folders/05/tx3h6q9d0fd357pwxqswnqb400007v/T/"
export USER="jenkins"
export WORKSPACE="/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/test"
export __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING="0xFB:0:0"
export com.apple.java.jvmMode="client"
export com.apple.java.jvmTask="CommandLine.java"
Finished: SUCCESS
```

. while executing the original test job, I ran `ps -ef | grep git` on a shell and got this:

```
251 64578 63290   0  2:05pm ??         0:00.22 /usr/bin/git clone --progress -o origin git@github.com:MyProjectRedacted/FR-Dev.git /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/fr-develop-latest
251 64579 64578   0  2:05pm ??         0:03.98 ssh git@github.com git-upload-pack 'EFEdcuationFirstMobile/FR-Dev.git'
251 64582 64578   0  2:05pm ??         0:03.36 git index-pack --stdin -v --fix-thin --keep=fetch-pack 64578 on ctx.ci.local
```

On a shell, running as user `jenkins`, executing the same command `/usr/bin/git clone --progress -o origin git@github.com:MyProjectRedacted/FR-Dev.git /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/fr-develop-latest` works just fine. the repository gets cloned.

I finally tried adding a new 'Execute Shell' build step, with the very same command.
It also works.

So... definitely something with the git plugin that's messing things up.
I have the SSH keys for the `jenkins` user setup correctly and I can connect to the remote git repo using ssh git@github.com

At this point I'm a bit stuck.
Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I saw similar symptoms, and I found that it was caused by a recursive delete of the workspace in the Jenkin's Git plugin clone() method (see code snippet, below).  In my case, we have numerous jobs that share a single custom workspace, so the delete call took hours to complete.  After removing the custom workspace, the clone operation finished successfully.

From https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/git/GitAPI.java:

```
final String source = remoteConfig.getURIs().get(0).toPrivateString();

listener.getLogger().println("Cloning repository " + source);
final int[] gitVer = getGitVersion();

try {
    workspace.deleteRecursive();  // This line was taking forever
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace(listener.error("Failed to clean the workspace"));
    throw new GitException("Failed to delete workspace", e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, problem solved, and turns out there wasn't a problem to begin with.

Two things happened that gave the impression `git clone` was hanging:

1. the progress wasn't being updated
2. the connection was incredibly slow yesterday

I actually forgot to stop the job and when I came back today, everything was just fine.
Cheers.